# Парсер на Node.JS выводит пустую строку

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, cheerio

есть простенький парсер

```
var needle = require('needle');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

url = "https://aliexpress.ru/item/32957196981.html?gps-id=pcDetail404&scm=1007.16891.96945.0&scm_id=1007.16891.96945.0&scm-url=1007.16891.96945.0&pvid=f1fb896d-1b1d-47ce-95d6-26abd9f3b7d1&_t=gps-id:pcDetail404,scm-url:1007.16891.96945.0,pvid:f1fb896d-1b1d-47ce-95d6-26abd9f3b7d1,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%238_668%23808%234094%23148_668%23888%233325%2313_668%232846%238115%23869_668%232717%237567%23961";

needle.get (url, function (err, res){
  if(err) throw(err);

  var $ = cheerio.load(res.body);

  console.log($(".product-title").text())
})
```

после запуска выводит пустую строку.
Вопрос к тем, кто делал парсеры, правильный в целом ли подход и что не так конкретно тут? спасибо )

Comment: а что хотелось увидеть?! по ссылке на странице тега с классом "product-title" даже ручной поиск не находит. Название товара сидит в теге script

Comment: через devtools клас «product-title» указывает на название товара

Comment: также и клас «product-name» так же выводит пустую строку

Comment: @ike77, когда ты смотришь в dev-tools уже отработали все js скрипты загружающие данные, когда ты загружаешь в своем коде - очевидно js скрипты не отрабатывают и ты получаешь просто html который приходит с сервера. В нем нет элементов с нужными тебе классами.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно содержимое, генерируемое скриптами. `cheerio` просто превращает HTML в DOM, но не запускает скрипты. Попробуйте библиотеки, которые воссоздают поведение браузера, например https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer