# html код в "коде страницы" chrome и полученный с помощью библиотеки requests не совпадают

Tags: python, html, requests

Я пытаюсь создать парсер для сайта "РешуЕГЭ" и при работе с модулем BeautifulSoup постоянно при выводе происходили необъяснимые, на первый взгляд, явления. Тогда я решил проверить, совпадает ли то, что я вижу в "коде страницы" google cgrome и то, что я получаю из requests.get('https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=191').text - выяснилось, что нет. Довольно простой и понятный html-код я вижу в хроме:

```
<p> созЫв</p>
<p> Отзыв (посла)</p>
<p> добелА</p>
<p> оптОвый</p>
<p> тубдиспансЕр</p>
```

И совершенный бред я вижу при выводе requests.get('https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=191').text:

```
<p> созЫв<p> Отзыв (посла)<p> добелА<p> оптОвый<p> тубдиспансЕр</p></p></p></p></p>
```

почему эти параграфы "съезжают" при попытке достичь сайта с помощью requests? И можно ли как-то исправить эту проблему?

Comment: А что Вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: Проблема разбиралась в отношении сайта aliexpress вот здесь
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138471/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-node-js-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83
- проблема в том, что правки в сайт вносятся скриптами, если смотреть в браузере, то скрипты отработали и вы видите правильный код, при скачивании JS код не отработал и вам выдается некорректный код. Для решения 2 пути: скачивать "отработавшую" страницу (запустить чз браузер и скачать) или читать некорректный код